# Calculating the mass function of maximum of a sum

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

Find an expression for the mass function of $N(t)$ in a renewal process whose interarrival times $X_i$ are a) poisson distributed with paramter $\lambda$ and b) gamma distributed $\Gamma(\lambda,b)$.

As a recall: $N(t)=\max\{ n: T_n \leq t \}$ with $T_n=X_1+...+X_n.$

I hope anybody can help me a little bit in a) so that I can do part b) by myself.

a)

$$f_{N(t)}(x)=\Pr(N(t)=x)=\Pr(\max\{ n: T_n \leq t \}=x)=\Pr(T_k )=f_{T_k},$$
for all $k\leq x$.
Is that right?

Comment: The part "$=\Pr(T_k )=f_{T_k}$" is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $T_0=0$, then, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$P(N(t)=n)=P(T_n\leqslant t)-P(T_{n+1}\leqslant t).$$

Comment: Thank you so far!! That helps already very much. 

Since $X_i$'s are independent poisson distributed variables, the sum is also poisson distributed. $$T_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i \tilde{} poiss(n \lambda).$$ Then we have: $$\Pr(T_n \leq t)=\sum_{k=0}^{t} \frac{e^{-n \lambda}(\lambda n)^k}{k!}.$$

Therfore: $$\Pr(N(t)=n)=\sum_{k=0}^{t} \frac{e^{-n \lambda}(\lambda n)^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{t} \frac{e^{-(n+1) \lambda}(\lambda (n+1))^k}{k!}.$$ Can I somehow calculate that?

Comment: Calculate meaning simplify? I do not think so. Actually one rarely considers renewal processes whose interarrival times are Poisson.